# Issue form submit after ajax_command_replace

Tags: ajax, forms

I have an issue with sending a form.

I have a form with some containers and 2 selects fields. The selects fields call the same callback who use "ajax_command_replace" to add some others fields and a submit button.

When I press the submit button, the page is refresh but my submit function is not called.

I need to do something in particular to call a function with "ajax_command_replace" ?

Here is my code for the submit button :

```
$addForm['button']['btn_submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    //'#submit' => array('f_form_submit'), not working too
    '#value' => t('Validate'),
);

$commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#z_btn",drupal_render($addForm));

function f_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    dpm($form_state);
}
```

Someone have an idea why my function is never called ?